# Stuttering some times using Gaffer's fixed timestamp on Android using OpenGLES 2.0

Tags: java, android, opengl-es, game-engine, game-loop

I am having some micro stutterings in my game loop.
I implemented correctly (I think) the fixed timestamp tecnique from https://gafferongames.com/post/fix_your_timestep/

I think when the tecnique is implemented correctly, the sprites movements are totally smooth. My code don't produces 100% of smoothing but is not bad at all.

**Surface class:**

```
public static final int FRAME_RATE = 30;
public static final double DELTA_TIME = 1/(double)FRAME_RATE;

private double lastTimeStamp;
private double accumulator;

// An entity position in the game
public float oldX, x;

@Override
public void onDrawFrame(GL10 unused) {
    double now = (System.nanoTime() - lastTimeStamp)/1000000 * 0.001;

    if (now > 0.25) {
        now = 0.25;
    }

    lastTimeStamp = System.nanoTime();
    accumulator += now;

    while (accumulator >= DELTA_TIME) {
        tick(DELTA_TIME);
        accumulator -= DELTA_TIME;
    }

    double alpha = accumulator/DELTA_TIME;

    render(alpha);
}

public void tick(double dt) {
    oldX = x;

    x++; // increment entity x position
}

public void render(double alpha) {
    float xx = (x - oldX) * (float)alpha + oldX; // interpolated x position

    ShaderBasic.render(fooTexture, xx, 0); // render class
}
```

**Shader class:**

```
public void render(Texture texture, float x, float y) {
    //RENDERING
    glUseProgram(glIdProgram);

    //VERTICES
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(glPosition);
    glVertexAttribPointer(glPosition, 2, GL_FLOAT, false, 0, texture.vertexBuffer);

    //UVS
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(glUv);
    glVertexAttribPointer(glUv, 2, GL_FLOAT, false, 0, texture.uvBuffer[0]);

    //MODEL
    glUniform2f(glTrans, x, y); 

    //RENDERING
    glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture.glIdTexture);
    glUniform1i(glTexture, 0);
    glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, 6, GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT, texture.indexBuffer);

    //DISABLE
    glDisableVertexAttribArray(glPosition);
    glDisableVertexAttribArray(glUv);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0);
```

}

**Vertex shader part:**

```
void main() {                       
    mat4 model = mat4(1.0,        0.0,       0.0, 0.0,
                      0.0,        1.0,       0.0, 0.0,
                      0.0,        0.0,       1.0, 0.0,
                      v_trans.x,  v_trans.y, 0.0, 1.0);

    mat4 projection = mat4(0.0036764, 0.0,        0.0, 0.0,
                           0.0,       0.0041666,  0.0, 0.0,
                           0.0,       0.0,        1.0, 0.0,
                           0.0,       0.0,        1.0, 1.0);

    gl_Position = projection * model * vec4(v_position, 0.0, 1.0);
    v_texCoord  = v_uv;
```

}

**Texture loader class:**

```
    private void loadImage(String imgPath, int frames) throws IOException {
        int[] id = new int[1];
        glGenTextures(1, id, 0);

        Bitmap img = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(Utils.getAssets().open(imgPath));
        glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, id[0]);
        glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR); // question
        glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR); // question
        glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
        glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
        GLUtils.texImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, img, 0);
        glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0);

        glIdTexture = id[0];
        width = img.getWidth();
        height = img.getHeight();

        this.frameWidth = width/frames;
        this.frameHeight = height;

        img.recycle();
}
```

**Another question:** when we use (x, y) coordinates with decimal part greater than 0, the texture filtering must be GL_LINEAR? I noticed when I use GL_NEAREST, the rendered sprite on the screen is sliced at some positions in the screen. I think GL_NEAREST not filter all the texture pixels when we have decimal imprecisions...

Thank you!!!!

Answer (score 0):

> My code don't produces 100% of smoothing but is not bad at all.

Are you hitting 60 FPS consistently? If you are not, then you will get some microstutter as Android OpenGL ES uses triple buffering and vsync, so the display swaps will never exactly match your application-side frame timing.

> Another question: when we use (x, y) coordinates with decimal part greater than 0, the texture filtering must be GL_LINEAR? I noticed when I use GL_NEAREST, the rendered sprite on the screen is sliced at some positions in the screen. I think GL_NEAREST not filter all the texture pixels when we have decimal imprecisions...

Correct, as the name implies `GL_NEAREST` just returns the nearest texel to the sample point, without any filtering. It's usually never what you want to use for anything that isn't 1:1 texel-to-pixel.

In future please only ask one question per post.